# Find the maximum value from the each set

Tags: matlab, matrix, max

I have 3 sets of data as shown in below:

```
A=[3 1 4 2;7 9 8 3;7 5 3 6;4 1 9 3]

B=[1 0 4 5;7 7 1 3;4 7 6 5;2 2 1 9] 

C=[9 1 3 7;9 6 5 5;1 4 3 2;0 3 2 1]
```

I need to find out the maximum value when comparing with each other.
for instance, for matrix [1x1] from each set,
A=3,B=1,C=9,thus maximum number is 9

for matrix [1x2],maximum value=1 and so on..

so the

```
final result =[9 1 4 7;9 9 8 5;7 7 6 6;4 3 9 9]
```

Any suggestion to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `max`. For the case with 3 matrices, just use

```
max(A, max(B, C))
```

If you have more than three matrices, writing those `max` statements can get tiring, so you would use `cat` before taking the maximum

```
max(cat(3, A, B, C, D, E), [], 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
A=[3 1 4 2;7 9 8 3;7 5 3 6;4 1 9 3];
 A = reshape(A,[1,numel(A)]);
 B=[1 0 4 5;7 7 1 3;4 7 6 5;2 2 1 9] ;
 B = reshape(B,[1,numel(B)]);
 C=[9 1 3 7;9 6 5 5;1 4 3 2;0 3 2 1];
 C = reshape(C,[1,numel(C)]);
 D = [A;B;C];
 for ii = 1:size(D,2)
  res(1,ii) = max(D(:,ii));
 end
 res = reshape(res,[4,4]);
```

Comment: This is not the way to go at all in Matlab. Some comments: `A = reshape(A, [1, numel(A)])` is the same thing as `A = A(:)`. Your entire for loop is the same as `res = max(D, [], 2)` or else `res = max(D')`. For loops for such basic calculations are highly discouraged in Matlab. Take a look at H.Musters answer to see the best way to approach this.

Comment: @Dan As much as I agree with you, I think that this answer does not deserve a downvote (it does produce a correct result, after all). Perhaps it does not deserve an upvote either, as it overcomplicates the solution.

Comment: @EitanT too late for me to undo unfortunately. I downvoted because I feel it misleads readers away from some of the most basic Matlab paradigms and so it is unnecessarily confusing.

Comment: @Dan You can undo your vote if you introduce even the slightest edit to the answer. But that's your choice of course. Your comment is still appreciated!